# Missing cov-manage-im binary

Tags: coverity

I tried to find cov-manage-im binary in bin directory of cov-analysis-linux64-2017.07 and cov-analysis-linux64-8.7.0 packages, but there isn't. 
However I can found the cov-manage-im.jar in both of them.
When I try to execute that jar file with:

```
java -jar cov-manage-im.jar
```

command results

```
no main manifest attribute, in cov-manage-im.jar
```

So, my question is: how to use cov-manage-im or other tool in those version to extract .csv file from Coverity server?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use cov-manage-im using the binaries provided by Coverity SCAN, please note that this tool is intentionally not available. It is only available for the use of our commercial users and requires a license.

The jar you seem to have found does not provide this functionality.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification. 
Is there any way to get machine readable information about any new issue of an open source project regularly build, uploaded and scanned by Coverity?